# replacing a "li-ion" HFC (3,2v) battery

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, charger, lifepo4

I have a device with containing **4** x (allegedly) *"Li-Ion"* **HFC** batteries **in serial**  but voltage is not 3.7 but **3.2V**.

labelled values "Li-Ion 3.2v HFC1450 series 500mAh 1.6Wh"

[image: batt HFC]

Just one of them measures 0.xV whereas others are alright, so it is clear that one is wrong and it has to be replaced.

As this type of batteries are not easy to find nor cheap and the required output voltage can be higher.

Is there any chance that i can replace by a different type of battery?
What can happen after replacing by a li-ion 3.7v ?

Ideas or suggestions?

Checking by internet it seems that technology is Lithium iron phosphate and not a Li-Ion
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_iron_phosphate_battery

Comment: "Is there any chance that i can replace by a different type of battery?" What are you using the cells for?

Comment: anything between 3V and 4V is normal for Li-Ion cells, depending on charge level

Comment: @SimSon i agree, after an internet search seems that batteries are LifePO4 BUT as you can see in the photo the labelling includes term "Li-Ion". I assume it was a mistake from the factory

Comment: Li-Ion is a generic term, LiFePO4 is one of the possible implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the picture. I was mistaken, they are LiFePO4. "HFC1450" is the term you need to search for. At least in my country they are available.